# Different between onclick on a button and onclick on select tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC.  I have a button that I click and a controller is called via AJAX. Data is returned and jquery is used to update the page:

**View**

```
<select class="form-control" id="select-templates-eb" style="width: 85%; display: inline;">
      <option disabled selected>--Select Template --</option>
       @foreach (Template t in Model.EmailBodyTemplates.Templates)
       {
            <option value="@t.TemplateId">@t.Name</option>
       }
 </select>
 <button  onclick="template_onClick('EB')" style="margin-bottom: 3pt;" >Load Template</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
 if(selectedType == 'EB')
    {
        var templateId = $('#select-templates-eb').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: "POST",
            url: GetTemplateURL,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id: templateId
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                var editor = $("#editor-eb").data("kendoEditor");
                editor.body.innerHTML = data.Text;
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                bootbox.alert(errMsg);
            }
        })
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetTemplate(int id)
{
    Template template = new Template();
    template = _templateLogic.GetTemplateByTemplateId(id);
    return Json(template, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If I put the "onclick" event on the `<SELECT>` tag, the page does not redirect and properly updates.  However, if I put the "onclick" event on the `<button>`, the page redirects by updating the query string.  Why is this? Does the onclick behave differently on a select tag vs a button?  How can I prevent this?

Comment: `select` triggers a `change` event, you might want to use this one instead of a click. I would recommend to use a proper `event-handler` instead of the `onclick`-attribute

Comment: Usually, you don't add onclick event on a select tag, rather an onchange event

Comment: The issue occurs with the button.  I do understand that you would use onchange if using SELECT, I only noticed that onclick works fine with select but not the same with the button

Comment: is there any form you are submitting with button ?? try e.preventDefault() in your script.